# Qt How can i send https request to server?

Tags: c++, qt, https, request

I tried to send get request with **https** url. Reply is empty but there is no error message. I download OpenSSL and copied **libeay32.dll** and **ssleay32.dll** files to C:\Qt\Qt5.1.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin folder.

Code:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QNetworkRequest request;
QNetworkReply *reply = NULL;

QSslConfiguration config = QSslConfiguration::defaultConfiguration();
config.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2);
request.setSslConfiguration(config);
request.setUrl(QUrl(url));
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ServerHeader, "application/json");

reply = manager->get(request);

qDebug() << reply->readAll();
```

Comment: Use [reply->error()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qnetworkreply.html#error)

Comment: get() triggers an /asynchronous/ operation. At the time you call readAll(), there's no data yet. Connect to the reply's finished() and error() signals and read the data in the slot connected to finished().

Answer (score 6):

As Frank wrote in his commet, the get function is asynchronous, so at the point you are trying to read the answer the http request might not even be completed yet.

To solve this, you need to handle the `finished` signal:

```
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this,
                 SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

and read the results in the handler:

```
void NetworkHandler::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
  qDebug() << reply->readAll();
}
```

Comment: I'm using `QObject::connect(&manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);` whre loop is `QEventLoop loop`. How can I use connect( ) without this event loop? for example into my methods where I won't have the QcoreApplication.

Comment: @jeffersonferreirapalheta you need an event loop to use QNetworkAccessManager. If your code does not run inside a QCoreApplication::exec() event loop then you're going to have to use the QEventLoop class, but be warned that it is considered to be sloppy code.